# Pandoc conversion of markdown to latex with default filename

Tags: r, knitr, pandoc

I'm using the [R package `knitr`](http://yihui.name/knitr) to generate a markdown file `test.md`. This file is then processed by `pandoc` to produce a variety of output formats, such as html and pdf. Because I want to use `bibtex` when generating the pdf through `latex`, I believe I have to tell `pandoc` to stop at the intermediate latex output, and then run `bibtex` and `pdflatex` myself (twice). Here's where I found a slight annoyance in my workflow: the only way I found for `pandoc` to keep the intermediate tex file, and not go all the way to the pdf, was to specify a hard-coded filename through the `-o` option with a `.tex` extension. This is problematic for me because I'm using [a config file](http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/pandoc/) to run `pandoc('test.md', "latex", "config.pandoc")` via `knitr` with options, which I would like to keep generic without hard-coded output filename:

```
format: latex
o: test.tex
s: 
S:
biblio: refs.bib
biblatex:
template: 'template.tex'
default-image-extension: pdf
```

which in turn becomes the following command for pandoc,

```
pandoc -s -S --biblio=refs.bib --default-image-extension=pdf --biblatex --template='template.tex'  -f markdown -t latex -o test.tex 'test.md'
```

If I skip the `o: test.tex` option, `pandoc` produces a pdf and doesn't keep the intermediate latex file. How can I keep the tex file, without specifying this hard-coded filename?

Comment: I'll think about this, if pandoc really cannot keep the intermediate tex file.

Comment: one option would be to specify `-o` in the `knitr::pandoc()` call, with default value the same basename as the input file. But I think it would be nicer to find a solution from the pandoc side; it's very possible that I missed an option to keep the tex file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve this problem on my side, I added a new argument `ext` to the `pandoc()` function. It is available [on Github now](https://github.com/yihui/knitr#readme) (knitr development version 1.3.6). You can override the default file extension, e.g.

```
library(knitr)
pandoc(..., ext = 'tex')
```